# Rewrite this SQL query without HAVING clause?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, view, inline

Here is the original query:

```
select flavor, max(price) mp 
    from Product 
    where flavor != 'chocolate' 
    group by flavor having avg(price) < 4
    order by flavor;
```

I was tasked with rewriting this query without a HAVING clause, but I am still learning this stuff, and I'm not really sure how to approach this exactly. As a hint, I was told to use an inline view, but I keep getting errors with my query.

And here is the query I wrote:

`select flavor,  max(price) mp 
    from (select flavor, price, avg(price) ap 
    from Product 
    where flavor != 'chocolate' group by flavor,price) prod 
    where ap < 4 
    group by flavor 
    order by flavor;`

I still get 1 extra row in my result. What is not the same about my query?

Comment: You should be calculating MAX with AVG; selecting `price` like you currently are will result in an effectively random price chosen for each product flavor. ...what is the problem with using a HAVING anyway?

Comment: Have you tried putting the avg on the `where` filter?

Comment: It's an exercise for a class to understand subqueries better and inline views. I finally got it, @Tom had the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need something like:

```
select prod.flavor, prod.MaxPrice
from (
    select flavor, max(price) AS MaxPrice, avg(price) AS AvgPrice
    from Product 
    where flavor != 'chocolate' 
    group by flavor) prod 
where prod.AvgPrice < 4 
order by flavor;
```